# What data before the code segment in PE files?

Tags: windows, pe-resources

According to IDA the file I'm inspecting has `imagebase 0x400000`. The first data I can see starts at `0x401000` but the program reads some data which is at `00400174`.

When I put a data access breakpoint there, it breaks in `ntdll!RtlpImageDirectoryEntryToData32` which probably means that there is some process data (using Windows 7). Where can I find some information as to what exactly is there stored?

From the call stack it looks like there should be some resource data as there is
`FindResource` among other things.

```
ChildEBP RetAddr  
0012f998 7c910385 ntdll!RtlpImageDirectoryEntryToData32+0xf
0012f9b8 7c9118c0 ntdll!RtlImageDirectoryEntryToData+0x57
0012fa84 7c911db7 ntdll!LdrpSearchResourceSection_U+0x34
0012faa0 7c80ad8b ntdll!LdrFindResource_U+0x18
0012faf4 7e419dbb kernel32!FindResourceExW+0x64
0012fb18 7e42c924 user32!LoadStringOrError+0x31
0012fb3c 00404bcd user32!LoadStringA+0x1c
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data at virtual address `00400174` is the `IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY` entry for `IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_RESOURCE`.

Read the PE/COFF specification at http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/c/5/9c5b2167-8017-4bae-9fde-d599bac8184a/pecoff_v83.docx, and use either a hex editor or a PE editor to navigate through the PE header content.